# Python Quick Question about writing a dataframe to csv-Naming conventions

Tags: python, sql

I have to read a table every 30 minutes and I have made the query which only takes updates rows.

```
dfsql = client.query(sql, project=project_id).to_dataframe()
```

I have already existing table when I created dataframe for the first time using this

```
dfsql.to_csv('/home/analytics/divyang/divyangtest.csv')
```

Now,I want to write the updated records into a new table (not in divyangtest.csv) so each time my query runs, I should have a new table like divyangtest1,divyangtest2 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding the time to it - guaranteeing a unique name and making it easier to understand when the file was made.

Make the filename something like this:

```
filename = f"divyangtest-{datetime.datetime.now()}.csv"
```

I just ran it and it came up with this:

```
'divyangtest-2020-06-17 13:14:37.114370.csv'
```

You can tidy it up to make the file to be whatever you like as well.

Here's a (messy) example that makes it look neat:

```
filename = f"divyangtest_{str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0].replace(' ', '_')}.csv"
```

This makes the filename look like this:

```
'divyangtest_2020-06-17_13:17:25.csv'
```

Let me know if you have any more questions in the comments.

#### Writing the file

Try this:

```
filename = f"divyangtest_{str(datetime.datetime.now()).split('.')[0].replace(' ', '_')}.csv"
dfsql.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks Ash.One last question- how do I write filename = f"divyangtest-{datetime.datetime.now()}.csv" into? dfsql.to_csv('/home/analytics/divyang/divyangtest.csv')

Comment: Hi Divyang! Good question, I'll update it in the question now.